# You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `getInitialProps` in pages/_app

Tags: next.js, internationalization, server-side-rendering

*Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`. This does not opt-out pages with `getStaticProps`*

**How do I fix this annoying warning ? That's how my _app.tsx looks like**

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import "../styles/globals.scss";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

const MyApp: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

In Layout I have Footer which import "next-translate/useTranslation"; for i18n transaltions, maybe this somehow causing it.

```
function Contacts() {
  const { t } = useTranslation("translations");

  return (
    <footer className={styles.contacts}>
      <div className={styles.contacts__main}>
        <h1 className={styles.contacts__header}>{t("contacts")}</h1>
    ....
```

Comment: In my case, my backend was out...