# You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`?

Tags: next.js

I am building a next js app. In my project I am getting a warning. Can anyone help me to get rid of those type of warning. Please help me.

Hello, I am using custom app like this-

```
import { ColorScheme, ColorSchemeProvider, Global, MantineProvider } from '@mantine/core'
import { getCookie, setCookie } from 'cookies-next'
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes'
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { useState } from 'react'

type Props = AppProps & { colorScheme: ColorScheme }

export default function App({ Component, pageProps, colorScheme: _colorScheme }: Props) {
  const [colorScheme, setColorScheme] = useState<ColorScheme>(_colorScheme)

  const toggleColorScheme = (value?: ColorScheme) => {
    const nextColorScheme = value || (colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark')
    setColorScheme(nextColorScheme)
    setCookie('mantine-ui-colorScheme', nextColorScheme, { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 })
  }

  return (
    <>
      {/* need add next-themes failback */}
      <Global styles={() => ({
        ':root': { background: '#fff', color: '#000' },
        '[data-theme="dark"]': { background: '#1A1B1E', color: '#C1C2C5' }
      })} />
      {/* next-themes theme provider */}
      <ThemeProvider enableSystem={false}>
        {/* mantine color scheme provider */}
        <ColorSchemeProvider colorScheme={colorScheme} toggleColorScheme={toggleColorScheme}>
          <MantineProvider theme={{ colorScheme }} withGlobalStyles withNormalizeCSS>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </MantineProvider>
        </ColorSchemeProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  )
}
App.getInitialProps = ({ ctx }: { ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext }) => ({
  colorScheme: getCookie('mantine-ui-colorScheme', ctx) || 'light',
})
```

After that when I build my project I am getting this warning-

```
Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`. This does not opt-out pages with `getStaticProps`
```

How to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 3):

Pages with `getInitialProps` are run on demand. If that happens next.js is not able to perform [Automatic Static Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73271176/you-have-opted-out-of-automatic-static-optimization-due-to-getinitialprops-in). ASO is used when Next.js detects that a page is static (can be prerendered), meaning it has no blocking data requirements. This determination is made by the absence of `getServerSideProps` and `getInitialProps` in the page.

That is why `getStaticProps` is recommended over `getInitialProps`.

Unfortunately, getStaticProps is not available on `pages/_app`. So either we can add getStaticProps on all pages. Or we have to continue with the warning.